# Construct struct with passed array

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, nested

Im trying to make next code to work, but have "No constructor" error.

```
struct SimpleStruct{
    const size_t i;
    constexpr SimpleStruct(const size_t i) : i(i) {}
};

struct ComplexStruct{
    const SimpleStruct* const array_;
    constexpr ComplexStruct(const SimpleStruct* const array) : array_(array) {}
};

constexpr SimpleStruct simple_arr[] = { {1}, {2}, {3} } ;
constexpr ComplexStruct complex_fail = { {1}, {1}, {1} };

constexpr ComplexStruct complex_ok = {simple_arr} ;
```

How can i make it, without additional entities?

Comment: If there aren't "additional entities", then there's no valid object for `complex_fail.array_` to point at. Could you just use a `std::vector<SimpleStruct>` instead of raw pointer?

Comment: Please write this like post, to i can mark as answer.

PS no i cant use vector or other dynamic memory.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, that's asking the compiler to do a lot. I got it to compile with this:

```
constexpr ComplexStruct complex_fail { (SimpleStruct[]) { {1}, {1}, {1} } };
```

I couldn't find a way to use it with a modern `static_cast<>`.

Comment: I think this will get you a dangling pointer to a temporary array object which was immediately destroyed.

Comment: You might be right. I didn't notice the pointers bits.